# How do I avoid CLS (cumulative layout shift) with Google Adsense "Let Google optimize the size of your mobile ads" enabled?

Tags: core-web-vitals, web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift

I am not using responsive ads due to the willing of getting a better Web Vitals score.

However, with the `Let Google optimize the size of your mobile ads` checked, it seems Google will still change/update its ad size in a `min-height` defined container by modifying the CSS property to this:

```
height: auto !important;
min-height: 0px !important;
```

Is there any way can fix it?

I don't want to uncheck it because the revenue would drop.

[image]

[image: Google Adsense - Let Google optimize the size of your mobile ads]

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of great references on how to reduce CLS with Google Adsense ([ref1](https://mediarealm.com.au/articles/google-adsense-reducing-cls-cumulative-layout-shift/) and [ref2](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/guides/minimize-layout-shift)):

> The best method is to add a min-height value to a wrapper around each of your ad units. However, using a class to target this CSS property isn’t enough – you will need to use an ID to target this wrapper. For some unknown reason, Google AdSense’s Javascript strips out min-height directives on any parent objects.
> **However, they do not strip this out if you use an ID to do the CSS** targeting.

So the trick is to add an `id` to target your container's CSS, and that should bring down your CLS to 0!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work in 2023

Answer (score 0):

The min-height in a div with an id
[see answer #1 or here: https://mediarealm.com.au/articles/google-adsense-reducing-cls-cumulative-layout-shift/ ]
helps... but still has difficulty with responsive layouts in Bootstrap.

If you use Adsense auto-ads Adsense will insert ads whereever it thinks is best and that means altering the height of these elements:

```
<div class="row">
```

which Adsense changes to

```
<div class="row" style="height: auto !important;">
```

and pagespeed also complains about CLS with

```
<div class="alert">
```

It may be possible to apply the unique ID approach to the row and alert divs in Bootstrap, (without setting a min height, since on most websites every page is different) but even if that works, that would cut into ad revenues.  It seems this is Catch-22 - you can have great core vitals OR great adsense optimization, but not both. It's up to Adsense to find a solution, presumably by predicting optimal ad positions, layouts and sizes prior to rendering the page, so thereis no CLS.